# error MSB4018: The "LocPayloadAddProject" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: localization

My new localization build setup failed on Localization.targets error MSB4018: The "LocPayloadAddProject" task failed unexpectedly. Can someone tell me what went wrong?

errors:
2017/01/26 11:31:04 AM         6>E:.BtCxCache\Localization.2.0.22.7\Localization.targets(780,5): error MSB4018: The "LocPayloadAddProject" task failed unexpectedly. [E:\bt\775626\repo\src\loc\Ux\Extensions\GalleryPackages\Compute\CreateAvailabilitySet.locbld\locbld.proj]
2017/01/26 11:31:04 AM    E:.BtCxCache\Localization.2.0.22.7\Localization.targets(780,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'E:\bt\775626\repo\out\retail-amd64-localization\CreateAvailabilitySet\lbaworking\default\CreateAvailabilitySet\locstudio.source'. [E:\bt\775626\repo\src\loc\Ux\Extensions\GalleryPackages\Compute\CreateAvailabilitySet.locbld\locbld.proj]

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from colleague and it solved the issue.

The LBA seeding didn't run correctly. There are no lba.config in each project folder under lba. i.e. "D:\Source\Repo\rdnext\AzureUX\IaaSExp\src\loc\Ux\Extensions\GalleryPackages\Compute\CreateAvailabilitySet.locbld\lba\cs\CreateAvailabilitySet\LBA.config"

Just set enable_locseeding=1 to make the file get copied correctly.